# Custom Post Type canonical link / pagination redirecting to root

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, pagination, redirect

I have inherited an existing site and have recently been asked to make some changes.

They have 'renamed' the default post as 'latest-news' using this 'my_new_default_post_type':

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1 );

    function my_new_default_post_type() {

      register_post_type( 'post', array(
          'labels' => array(
              'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
          ),
          'public'  => true,
          '_builtin' => false,
          '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
          'capability_type' => 'post',
          'map_meta_cap' => true,
          'hierarchical' => false,
          'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'latest-news','with_front' => false),
          'query_var' => true,
          'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
      ) );

  }

?>
```

These can be seen being listed on a standard page here:

https://gateleyplc.com/news-events/latest-news/

with the second page of pagination here:

https://gateleyplc.com/news-events/latest-news/page/2/

Clicking into a post loads it here:

https://gateleyplc.com/latest-news/gateley-plc-celebrates-sixth-anniversary-in-yorkshire-with-the-appointment-of-six-new-solicitors/

I have added some new custom post types, one example of which is 'corparate-deals'. The code to add this custom post type is:

```
<?php

    add_action('init', 'corporate_deals_register');

    function corporate_deals_register() {

     $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Corporate Deals', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Corporate Deals', 'post type singular     name'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Briefing'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit briefing'),
        'new_item' => __('New briefing'),
        'view_item' => __('View briefing'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Corporate Deals'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'publicly_queriable' => false,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus'  => false,
      'exclude_from_search' => false,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-add-page',  // Icon Path
      'menu_position' => 5,
      'show_in_menu'  =>    'blogs_menu',
      'query_var' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'corporate-deals' , $args );
  }

?>
```

You can see these listed here:

https://gateleyplc.com/corporate-deals

and clicking into one here:

https://gateleyplc.com/corporate-deals/gateley-corporate-team-advises-on-firms-acquisition-of-kiddy-partners/

**However...** when you try to view the second page of pagination, here:

https://gateleyplc.com/corporate-deals/page/2/

it redirects to:

https://gateleyplc.com

I have searched high and low for any redirects or rewrite rules but cannot find any.

One thing I did notice is that if I add:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'latest-news','with_front' => false),
```

to my custom post declaration (i.e. rewriting the 'corporate-deals' to 'latest-news') then the redirection doesn't occur.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Additionally**

The code that builds the post listing is:

```
<?php // Corporate Deals

function paginatedcorporatedeals_func( $atts ) {

  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'pageid' => '{$pageid}',
    'title' => '{$title}',
    'showcontent' => '{$showcontent}',
    'newsurl' => '{$newsurl}',
    'postmeta' => '{$postmeta}'
  ), $atts ) );

  $output;

  global $post;

  $ws = 1;

  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

  $args = array(
    'post_type'=>'corporate-deals',
    //'order'=>'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 16,
    'paged' => $paged,
  );

  $slug = the_slug();

  query_posts($args);

  // global $wp_query;

  // $postcount = $wp_query->found_posts;

  $count=0;

  if(have_posts()) {

    $divider = 'yes';
    $featuredimg = 'date';
    $truncate = 250;

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

      global $post;

      $thetitle = get_the_title($post->ID);

      require get_template_directory() . '/assets/inc/plugins/vc-intergration/modules/shortcode-templates/media-list.php';

      $output .="<hr>";

      $count++;

    endwhile;

    $output .=  "<div class='vc_row clearfix'><div class='white-bar'>".page_pagination()."</div></div>";

    wp_reset_query();
  }

  return $output;

}

add_shortcode( 'paginatedcorporatedeals', 'paginatedcorporatedeals_func' );

?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have created `https://gateleyplc.com/corporate-deals` as a page with a shortcode, rather than use the custom post type archive page that WordPress generates?

Comment: I would rather have used an archive page as you suggest. I was trying to follow the existing layout/standards that the site has been built with. The page remains editable 'around' the list content and styling wise is in-keeping with the 'latest-news' list page. 

Restyling the auto generated archive pages to match the 'latest-news' page and list plugin will be my last resort. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: When you visit `/corporate-deals/page/2/`, WordPress is querying for the 2nd page of a singular `corporate-deals` post with the slug `page`. If you used the built-in archive instead of a page, this issue would disappear. You'll need to add your own rewrite rules to override the ones generated for your post type.

Answer (score 0):

just remove template redirect using remove template_redirect filter

use below code to stop the canonical redirect.

`remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');`

Comment: I added that at the bottom of functions.php for the theme and unfortunately it is still redirecting.

Comment: You should test for a specific condition in `redirect_canonical` and return `false` in that one case rather than completely remove the filter, which will break all kinds of other cases where you will want that redirect.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the reason for these paging problems is `'publicly_queriable' => false,` in your `$args` for `register_post_type()`. Change it to `TRUE` (default value) or comment out and pagination will work.

`publicly_queriable` argument should not be false unless the post type you are registering is not public.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it didn't work (although I think your suggestion is the right thing to do generally.) Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Changing the method may help. There needs to be a function.

```
<?php

function wpdocs_get_paginated_links( $query ) {
// When we're on page 1, 'paged' is 0, but we're counting from 1,
// so we're using max() to get 1 instead of 0
$currentPage = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ) );

// This creates an array with all available page numbers, if there
// is only *one* page, max_num_pages will return 0, so here we also
// use the max() function to make sure we'll always get 1
$pages = range( 1, max( 1, $query->max_num_pages ) );

// Now, map over $pages and return the page number, the url to that
// page and a boolean indicating whether that number is the current page
return array_map( function( $page ) use ( $currentPage ) {
return ( object ) array(
"isCurrent" => $page == $currentPage,
"page" => $page,
"url" => get_pagenum_link( $page )
);
}, $pages );
}

?>
```

And now you can use logic to display the pagination, don't forget is have to be outside the loop.

```
<!-- PAGINATION : begin -->
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args2s = array(
   'post_type' => 'portfolio_page',
   'posts_per_page' => 9,
   'paged' => $paged,

);
$categorie_portfolio = new WP_Query($args2s);
 if ($categorie_portfolio->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
    <nav class="pagination">
      <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Pagination</h2>
    <ul class="pagination__list">

    <?php foreach( wpdocs_get_paginated_links( $categorie_portfolio ) as $link ) : ?>
    <?php if ( $link->isCurrent ): ?>
    <li class="pagination__item pagination__item--current"><a href="<?php esc_attr_e( $link->url ) ?>" class="pagination__item-link"><?php _e( $link->page ) ?></a></li>

    <?php else : ?>
    <li class="pagination__item" ><a href="<?php esc_attr_e( $link->url ) ?>" class="pagination__item-link"><?php _e( $link->page ) ?></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>

    <!-- PAGINATION : end -->
    <?php endif; ?>
?>
```